# Appending negative numbers (Python)

Tags: python, append

I am creating a program that would get all the factors of a number(including its negative counterpart) for rational root theorem purposes.

I am successful in getting the positive roots but I can't seem to append the negative roots into my list and it just keeps requiring an input. Here's the code.

```
a = input("Number:")
c = []

for b in (1,a+1):
    if a%b == 0:
       c.append(b)

for d in c:
    e = (-1)*d
    c.append(d)

print c
```

So I tried deleting the "c.append(d)" part and replaced it with "print e". And it printed the negative factors.

Comment: Modifying the list you're iterating over is always a bad idea. In any language.

Comment: You have to cast your input to int "a = int(input())", and in the for loop use "for b in range(1,a+1)"

Comment: @lucasmullerm not in [tag:python2.7]

Comment: not the range or the int?

Comment: But if the OP is using [tag:python2.7], I agree he should use `int(raw_input())` instead of `input()`.

Comment: Yes, input is not raw_input, but without the range you're iterating through 2 items.

Answer (score 1):

1<sup>st</sup>, **never modify the list as you're looping over it, there is always a high chance something bad will happen**.

2<sup>nd</sup>, you call `for b in (1,a+1)`, you need a **`range`** before the `(1, a+1)`, as such: `for b in range(1,a+1)`.

3<sup>rd</sup>, if `print e` gives the correct info, then `e` must contain what you want to add. Thus, you can just add `c.append(e)` under `c.append(d)`.

4<sup>th</sup>, your use of `input()` leads me to think you are using [python2.x](/questions/tagged/python2.x). However, if this *is* the case, consider using `int(raw_input())` instead of `input()`. If you are *not* using [python2.x](/questions/tagged/python2.x), and using [python3.x](/questions/tagged/python3.x) then cast `int()` to your `input()` to make `int(input())`.

```
a = input("Number:")
c = []

for b in range(1,a+1):
    if a%b == 0:
       c.append(b)

temp = []

for d in c:
    e = (-1)*d
    temp.append(d)
    temp.append(e)

for i in temp:
    c.append(i)

print c
```

Answer (score 0):

You're appending the wrong variable. Try this:

```
a = int(input("Number: "))
c = []

for b in range(1, a+1):
    if a % b == 0:
        c.append(b)

for d in c:
    e = -1 * d
    c.append(e) # append the negated number instead of the original...
```

And yes, modifying the list you're iterating over is a bad idea. Try using a temp list instead.

Answer (score 0):

This may be simpler to read

```
a = input("Number:")

positives = []
for i in range(1, a+1):
    if a % i == 0:
        positives.append(i)

negatives = [-x for x in positives]

print 'positives:', positives
print 'negatives:', negatives
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are chasing your tail forever. Since you are appending one new item for each iteration. ie. you are looping over the "live" c, not a snapshot of what it was when the loop started.

```
for d in c:
    e = (-1)*d
    c.append(d)
```

Simpler to replace it with a list comprehension

```
c += [-d for d in c]
```

Here is a snippet that shows the problem of extending `c` on the fly

```
>>> for d in c:
...     print -d
...     c.append(-d)
... 
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
2
3
4
5
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
2
3
4
5
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
1
2
3
4
5
-1
-2
-3
-4
-5
```